# Target an element in Jquery if it is not inside another element

Tags: jquery

First fiddle shows the normal way my code works - if click on a span I get data-resendtext from closest .message-bubble element.
Not text, but attribute.

```js
$('.messages').on('click', '.message__action.message__edit[data-midedit]', function(e) {
    var t_edit = $(this),
        t_msg = t_edit.closest('.message-bubble');
        old_text = t_msg.find('[data-resendtext]').eq(0).attr('data-resendtext');
        alert(old_text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="1">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <p data-resendtext="First text">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="1">Click</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="2">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <p data-resendtext="Another text">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="2">Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR:    http://jsfiddle.net/kt8eavrz/

But occasionally (all data is loaded by ajax) I have a different .message-bubble element with quotation. The next fiddle shows the problem. I would like to get not the attribute data-resendtext from paragraph that is inside .resend_contain but the second one.
To be short - not "Another quotation" but "...text Id like to get".

```js
$('.messages').on('click', '.message__action.message__edit[data-midedit]', function(e) {
    var t_edit = $(this),
        t_msg = t_edit.closest('.message-bubble');
        old_text = t_msg.find('[data-resendtext]').eq(0).attr('data-resendtext');
        alert(old_text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="1">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <div class="message-text resend_contain">
        <div class="message-text-resend" style="display:none">
          <div class="message-text-resend-text">
            <p data-resendtext="A quotation">A quotation</p>
            <div></div><div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p data-resendtext="First text Id like to get">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="1">Click</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="2">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <div class="message-text resend_contain">
        <div class="message-text-resend" style="display:none">
          <div class="message-text-resend-text">
            <p data-resendtext="Another quotation">Another quotation</p>
            <div></div><div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p data-resendtext="Another text Id like to get">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="2">Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR:    http://jsfiddle.net/je5hyd42/

UPD - made this way

```
    if(t_msg.find('.resend_contain').length !== 0)
    {
        old_text = t_msg.find('[data-resendtext]').eq(1).attr('data-resendtext').trim();
    }
    else
    {
        old_text = t_msg.find('[data-resendtext]').eq(0).attr('data-resendtext').trim();
    }
```

Comment: So change `.eq(0)` to `.eq(1)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, if .eq(1) it wont work in first case, where is only 1 data-resendtext attr

Comment: I suppose the right way is to target data-resendtext that is not inside  message-text-resend div, but I failed to reproduce it in code(

Comment: You have not commented on my answer yet. Does it not solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem in a different way - always target the last data-resendtext attr.
 
old_text = t_msg.find('p').last().attr('data-resendtext').trim();

Comment: That is the equivalent way to what I did in my answer, just that my answer doesn't need any third party code. `Array.prototype.pop()` gives you the last array element. I really recommend to drop jQuery, or at least only use it after you learned how to do things without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Array.prototype.pop` here if you switch to vanilla JS (which I highly recommend, jQuery is really a thing of the past):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.messages').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.message__action.message__edit[data-midedit]')) {
      t_msg = event.target.closest('.message-bubble');
      old_text = [...t_msg.querySelectorAll('[data-resendtext]')].pop().dataset.resendtext;
      console.log(old_text);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="1">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <div class="message-text resend_contain">
        <div class="message-text-resend" style="display:none">
          <div class="message-text-resend-text">
            <p data-resendtext="A quotation">A quotation</p>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p data-resendtext="First text Id like to get">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="1">Click</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message-bubble" data-mid="2">
    <div class="message-bubble-inner">
      <div class="message-text resend_contain">
        <div class="message-text-resend" style="display:none">
          <div class="message-text-resend-text">
            <p data-resendtext="Another quotation">Another quotation</p>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p data-resendtext="Another text Id like to get">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="message__action message__edit" data-midedit="2">Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next index -1

```
old_text = t_msg.find('[data-resendtext]').eq(1).attr('data-resendtext');
```

Comment: eq(1) it wont work in first case, where is only 1 data-resendtext attr